# Redirect homepage to specific subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site and I need to redirect the homepage "http://members.slateadvisers.com/"

to the registration page

"http://members.slateadvisers.com/?action=registeruser&subscription=1"

How can I do this with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Insert this rule on top of all the rules just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members\.slateadvisers\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ ?action=registeruser&subscription=1 [L,R=301]
```